# Error related to const

Tags: c++, compilation, constants

In Visual Studio 2008, the following code will build successfully:

```
void Foo (int x);//Prototype

void Foo(const int x)//Implementation
{

}
```

However, this will generate an error (unresolved external symbol) during linking:

```
void Foo (int x);//Prototype

void Foo(const int x)//Implementation
{

}

void Bar()
{
    int x = 0;
    Foo(x);
}
```

The problem is because the function implementation for Foo specifies that the integer argument is constant, while the prototype does not require a constant.

Why does this happen? How come the problem isn't detected during compilation?

Comment: Ah, the call foo(x) in Bar() should be Foo(x) instead.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? 2002? 2003? 2005? 2008? 2010?

Comment: It's 2008. I'll edit that into the question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have a broken compiler. Broken compilers can choose their behavior themselfs. I know some compilers have this broken handling of that case.

Look on MSDN about a manual that documents that broken behavior. It works fine with compliant (non-broken in this regard) compilers.

Comment: I think this is the bug in question: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/421943/visual-c-typeid-should-ignore-top-level-const-of-function-arguments

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you call the function you call `foo`, but you have defined the `Foo` (with capital F). Both Foo's (re)declare the same function, because  top-level consts on parameters do not contribute to the function's signature. they are ignored if the declaration is not a definition and if it is a definition then the parameter variable is considered const inside the function. Think about it - if the parameter is passed as a copy (by value), then it is absolutely irrelevant for the caller whether the function will change the copy or not. That's why function declarations that differ only in *top-level* consts on their parameters are considered to declare the same function.

Comment: According to your answer there should be no question here.  You've not actually answered the question asked: Why the linker error, and why was it not detected at compile time?

Comment: @Noah: I bet there is a compile-time error. It is impossible that the compiler doesn't issue a diagnostic that foo is an undeclared identifier. Unless it is an extension which allows functions to be called without being declared which would produce a linker error when looking for definition of foo. Please remove the downvote - it is really uncalled for

Comment: +1 for the explanation of top-level consts - I didn't know this. As Johannes suggests, the actual problem is likely to be a broken compiler, but I appreciated the explanation of the red herring in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make absolutely sure that Armen is not crazy:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    static_assert( std::is_same<void(int ), void(const int )>::value, "...");
    static_assert(!std::is_same<void(int&), void(const int&)>::value, "...");
}
```

This should compile fine on any standard-conforming compiler with minimum C++0x support. If it does not, the compiler is broken. For example, g++ 4.5.1 accepts this code just fine.

And by the way, your actual problem is that you define a `Foo` but call a `foo` (note the different case).

Comment: And it does indeed compile it just fine.

Comment: @DeadMG: "It" being what? Visual Studio 2008 supports neither `<type_traits>` nor `static_assert`.

Comment: Yes, trying to include <type_traits> didn't work when I put this in VS2008. Strangely, there is this page on MSDN though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982077(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: @Only: If you install [SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en), you get [TR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1) which defines `<type_traits>`.

Answer (score -3):

Because you compile in C++, so the compiler considers the two functions (one with const param and one with non-const param) as two separate functions (with different decorated name). Only one of them is implemented, and the other one is used, hence the linking error.

Comment: NO! It does NOT. Top-level consts on parameters do not contribute to the function's signature. they are the same function!!!

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: What about this (Builds with MSVC 2010) int func ( int & x ) {return x;} int func ( const int& x ) {return x;} void Text() { func( 1 ); }

Comment: @Edwin: int vs const int is the same. int vs const int& is not, because one is reference on is not. int& vs const int& is not the same either because the const is not top-level. See C++ standard Overloading chapter

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: yes i forgot & on the first ( have editted but you were faster

Comment: @Edwin: To demonstrate the top-levelness: int * = int * const (top-level) int *  != const int * (not top-level)